# How do I target a specific element in an <article> using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-5.3

I need to access the text area with js and fill an input field in bootstrap modal.
I can access the title by writing this line:

```
event.target.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes[1].textContent;
```

But when it comes to the post body I cant access it this line:

```
event.target.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes[2].textContent;
```

Here is the html I'm using:

```
<article class="post col-md-6 ">
        <div class="media postforeach postborderleft">
            <div class="media-left media-top">

            </div>
            <div class="media-body">
                <header><h5 class="media-heading">{{ $post->title }}<i class="fa fa-angle-down pull-right " aria-hidden="true"></i></h5> </header>
                <p><i>{{ $post->body }}</i></p>
                <div class="info">
                    Posted by {{ $post->user->name }} on {{ $post->created_at }}
                </div>
              @if (Auth::check())
                <div class="interaction">
                      <a href="#" class="like">Like</a> |
                      <a href="#" class="like">Dislike</a>
                @if (Auth::user() == $post->user)
                        |
                      <a href="#" class="edit">Edit</a> |
                      <a href="{{ route('post.delete', ['post_id' => $post->id]) }}" class="like">Delete</a>
                 @endif
                </div>
              @else
                <a href="{{ route('registeration') }}" class="like" style="color: red">Login to interract with posts!</a>
              @endif
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
    </article>
```

and this is the whole js code:

```
$('.post').find('.edit').on('click',function(event) {
event.preventDefault();

var postTitle = event.target.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes[1].textContent;
var postBody = event.target.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes[2].textContent;
$('#post-title').val(postTitle);
$('#post-body').val(postBody);

$('#edit-model').modal();
});
```

Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: Try `event.target.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes[0].textContent` and `event.target.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes[1].textContent`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider marking the title and body with a class, e.g

```
<header class="post-title">...</header>
<p class="post-body>...</p>
```

Then traverse back up from the "edit" button to the post, then down to the title and body. The advantage is that this won't break even if you change your markup.

```
$('.post .edit').on('click', function(event) {
  var post = $(event.target).closest('.post');
  var postTitle = post.find('.post-title').text();
  var postBody = post.find('.post-body').text();
  // ...
});
```

Comment: Well that absolutely works! Thanks for the help mate :)

Comment: HI there. I have been using this for a while now and I came across a problem when trying to update some title and body with ajax-jason Here is the code I'm using to update: $(postTitleElement).text(msg['new_title']); I know I shouldnt use .text here but I dont know what I should use eaither. coul you help me by any with that? thanks

Comment: make sure you're updating the right DOM element - in your case it's probably the `<h5>` element, where you originally put the text. What element is `postTitleElement` pointing to?

Comment: It is pointing to `<h5>` just like you stated. But what should I change in the js code? Sorry for my lack of js knowledge

Comment: I suggest opening a new question describing the problem in detail. Notice that if you replace the text of the entire `<h5>` element you may replace the other sub-elements including e.g the `<i>` element. If you do open a new question, link to it in a comment here

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41921838/updating-post-with-bootstrap-modal-using-ajaxlaravel-ive-problems-with-json-pa

Comment: I got post ban sincr the community does not seem to like my questions -_- so I created the question in another acc

Answer (score 1):

This is due to whitespace between the child nodes of that `.media-body`, which become `Text` nodes in the DOM when parsed.

You should use either

```
var postBody = event.target.parentNode.parentNode.children[1].textContent;
```

or

```
var postBody = event.target.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes[3].textContent;
```

Or better yet, rewrite your markup to have a properly selectable `{{ $post->body }}` container (e.g. add a class to that `<p>`), and use selection from a common ancestor (likely the `.media-body`) instead of a hard-coded node traversal.

*EDIT:*
Also, since you're already using jQuery, why don't you use the jQuery's proper DOM traversal syntax:

```
var $mediaBody = $(this).parents('.media-body'),
    postTitle = $mediaBody.find('.media-heading').text(),
    postBody = $mediaBody.find('p:first').text();
```

Comment: Great explanation about the whitespace