# updating post with bootstrap modal using ajax+laravel I've problems with json part

Tags: json, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I'm trying to update posts with ajax and to do so, I use bootstrap modal, I previously had problems with filling my modal but I solved it by targetting elements with jquery now I'm having problems with saving and closing the modal I assume the problem caused by  the `.done` part. Any help is appreciated.
Here is the js file where I have my code for editing:

```
var postId = 0;
var postBodyElement = null;
var postTitleElement = null;

$('.post').find('.edit').on('click',function(event) {
event.preventDefault();

 var post = $(event.target).closest('.post');
 postTitleElement = post.find('.post-title').text();
 postBodyElement = post.find('.post-body').text();

 var postTitle = postTitleElement;
 var postBody = postBodyElement;

 postId = event.target.parentNode.parentNode.dataset['postid'];

 $('#post-title').val(postTitle);
 $('#post-body').val(postBody);

 $('#edit-modal').modal();
});

$('#modal-save').on('click', function() {
$.ajax({
    method: 'Post',
    url: urlEdit,
    data: {title: $('#post-title').val(), body: $('#post-body').val(),postId: postId, _token: token}
})
    .done(function (msg){

        $(postTitleElement).text(msg['new_title']);
        $(postBodyElement).text(msg['new_body']);
        $('#edit-modal').modal('hide');
    });
});
```

I'm predicting

```
    $(postTitleElement).text(msg['new_title']);
    $(postBodyElement).text(msg['new_body']);
```

Is where I have the problem and instead of `.text` I must do something else.
Also I have problems with all my bootstrap javascript components since I started working on editing.

Here is the modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="edit-modal">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Edit the Article</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form action="">
                    <div class="datasetpost form-group">
                        <label for="post-title">Title</label>

                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" id="post-title">
                        <br>
                        <label for="post-body">Post Body</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" name="post-body" id="post-body" cols="60" rows="10"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="modal-save">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

This is where they will appear:

```
<div class="media-body">
                <header class="post-title"><h5 class="media-heading">{{ $post->title }}<i class="fa fa-angle-down pull-right " aria-hidden="true"></i></h5> </header>
                <p class="post-body"><i>{{ $post->body }}</i></p>
                <div class="info">
                    Posted by {{ $post->user->name }} on {{ $post->created_at }}
                </div>
              @if (Auth::check())
                <div class="interaction">
                      <a href="#" class="like">Like</a> |
                      <a href="#" class="like">Dislike</a>
                @if (Auth::user() == $post->user)
                        |
                      <a href="#" class="edit">Edit</a> |
                      <a href="{{ route('post.delete', ['post_id' => $post->id]) }}" class="like">Delete</a>
                 @endif
                </div>
              @else
                <a href="{{ route('registeration') }}" class="like" style="color: red">Login to interract with posts!</a>
              @endif
            </div>
```

And my guess for the the solution would be something inside `.done()`
Because I'm already sending `.text` as you can see in js file since I have these lines:

```
 var post = $(event.target).closest('.post');
 postTitleElement = post.find('.post-title').text();
 postBodyElement = post.find('.post-body').text();

 var postTitle = postTitleElement;
 var postBody = postBodyElement;

 postId = event.target.parentNode.parentNode.dataset['postid'];

 $('#post-title').val(postTitle);
 $('#post-body').val(postBody);
```

For example `postBodyTitle` has `.text` at it's ending when I assigne the `.post-title` 
But I again try to turn it into `.text` or something inside `.done()`? and than the fun begins?

Comment: (1) include the markup, it's very relevant. Include where `#post-title`, `#modal-save`, as well as `.post` and friends appear. (2) are you sure `msg` in the `done()` callback has the right fields? dump it to `console.log` and check. (3) consider re-querying postTitle and postBody - the call to `modal()` may have replaced the dom elements with new ones.

Comment: @orip There you go I added some more usefull stuff.

Comment: @orip Did you manage to figure anything out? Cuz it seems like the problem is not inside `.done` I changed the code a bit and it is still the same, I also tried deleting whole js file to see if my other bootstrap scripts working or not and nothing changed, in this case I assume the problem is a bit deeper